# Change color of matching words, selected text, and matching brackets in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to change the foreground/background color of three things in Visual Studio Code. Is there a setting for these?

## matching words

In this screenshot, my cursor is on `thisTest` in line 15 and so all instances of `thisTest` are "highlighted". I have not selected the word. My cursor is between the `s` and `T`.

[image]

## selected words

In this screenshot I have selected `true`.

[image]

## matching brackets

In this screenshot my cursor is after `}` and both `{` and `}` are highlighted

[image]

Answer (score 1):

sorry for being late to the party. Let me share the configuration that works for me. In the `settings.json` file, you should have the following objects:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "[Hack The Box]": {
            // ... omitted for brevity
            "editor.selectionBackground": "#ff0000",
            "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#9fef00",
        }
    },
```

In my case, I had to overwrite the config of the `Hack The Box` I use. Let me recap the keys used:

- `editor.selectionBackground`: manages the `selected words` scenario
- `editor.selectionHighlightBackground`: manages the `matching words` scenario

Now, let's switch to brackets. For some time, the extension `Bracket Pair Colorizer` has been deprecated. To overcome this, you should update to the latest version VSCode. Then, be sure to have these settings (adjust based on your preferences):

```json
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
"editor.guides.bracketPairsHorizontal": false,
"editor.guides.highlightActiveBracketPair": false,
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
```

> Note that these settings are not scoped to a certain theme.

Let me know if this solve your issue!